# How to change default Microphone configuration on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, sound, pulseaudio, intel, microphone

I'am using `arecord` to record my voice with internal microphone for testing and `aplay` to heard this. The problem occurred is:

Using `arecord -f cd -d 10 test.wav` and speak "Hi, testing...." and after `aplay test.wav` i heard my voice. The command show output:

> Recording WAVE 'test.wav' : Signed 16 bit Little Endian, Rate 44100 Hz, Stereo

But using `arecord -d 10 test.wav` and after `aplay test.wav` i dont heard my voice. The command show output:

> Recording WAVE 'test.wav' : Unsigned 8 bit, Rate 8000 Hz, Mono

Using the first test i hear my voice, therefore, how i configure my internal microphone to using the (Signed 16 bit Little Endian, Rate 44100 Hz, Stereo) configuration? Because in others applications (Skype, Hangouts, Facebook Calling, ...) my microphone did not work.

Computer: Lenovo 320 15IKB

Distro: Ubuntu 16.04

My outputs for additional helper are present in: [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/YwBqpc9u)

Comment: Have you found any solution to this problem?

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of ways in which you can configure those applications to work.  Some of them will have a settings option, of which you can go into the program and use their audio setting interface to test and choose the device which has the best performance.

I just checked and Google Hangouts does have this feature to choose the audio device by name.  That's basically a GUI interface to what you are using the `aplay` and `arecord` commandline to check and use.

Some programs may not have an easy to settings interface.  Those applications will use your system's default settings for input.  Even the ones that do have a user-configurable audio settings interface, they still default to the system's default audio input unless you have manually set it different for that program.

### Setting your system default input Device

About the easiest way to get started with a new program is to set your system settings to use your preferred audio input device.  You can do this from Ubuntu's **System Settings**.  You can find it by clicking on:

> **System Settings** (the gear icon at the top right of the screen) -> (click) **Sound** -> (click) **Input**.

*(You can click on the Speaker Icon as a shortcut to get to this setting).*

From this `Input` tab select the preferred device.  When you select it you can also adjust the input level (or mute the ones you don't want to use if you have more than one, to avoid conflict.).

The highlighted one will be your system's default.  That is the one that the applications you mentioned (Skype, Hangouts, Facebook Calling, ...) will use unless you go into those applications and specifically change them to something different than your system's default.